# C++ char return outputting symbols

Tags: c++, function, char

I'm working on returning a char from a function. Everything works fine when I get these weird symbols on the screen.

```
#include <iostream>

void testfunc(char* outStr);

int main()
{
  char FirstName[10];
  testfunc(FirstName);
  std::cout << "So far so good.";
  std::cout << std::endl;
  std::cout << FirstName;
  std::cout << std::endl;
  std::cout << "It worked!";
  std::cout << std::endl;
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}

void testfunc(char* outStr)
{
  char FirstName[10];
  std::cin >> FirstName; 
  outStr = FirstName;
}
```

I have a picture of the problem but it seems I can't post any. the output looks like random bloks followed by numbers and symbols. It's not an address. It does compile and run through the program fine. the cout's before and after FirstName, all output just fine. FirstName itself, however, outputs symbols and blocks.

Comment: `outStr = FirstName` only copies the direction. use `strcpy(outStr, FirstName)`. Or better yet, use `std::string`

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of that particular question; the offending line is `outStr = FirstName` which appears to be an attempt to *copy* the array contents.

Comment: 1. The `FirstName` array in `testfunc()` gets invalid as soon the function returns. 2. `outStr = FirstName;` is actually useless, it doesn't change the `char FirstName[10];` declared in `main()` (hint, try `strncpy()` instead of `=`!)

Answer (score 3):

`outStr = FirstName` doesn't actually copy the string, it just assigns the `outStr` parameter variable to point to the first element of the `FirstName` array within `testfunc()`; the `FirstName` array within `main()` is not modified.

Either use `strcpy()` to copy the string, or (better yet) use `std::string` instead of character arrays.